# Why are these functions still get executed asynchronously despite using Async module

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, async.js

I decided to use Async module to populate a mongodb collection in the order that I want.
Without Async the code works but the documents aren't inserted in the proper order:

```
function insertRowInBLD(ref, riskstatements, maximpact, controleffectiveness, recommendedriskrating, frequency, impact, validatedreviewriskrating, rationalforriskadjustment) {
    const businessLineDashboard = new BusinessLineDashboard({
        ref: ref,
        riskstatements: riskstatements,
        maximpact: maximpact,
        controleffectiveness: controleffectiveness,
        recommendedriskrating: recommendedriskrating,
        frequency: frequency,
        impact: impact,
        validatedreviewriskrating: validatedreviewriskrating,
        rationalforriskadjustment: rationalforriskadjustment
    });
    businessLineDashboard.save()
        .then(row => {
            console.log('row ' + businessLineDashboard.ref + ' has been inserted succesfully');
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('err: ', err);
        });
}
```

I wanted the the "documents" to be inserted in that order. Because of the asynchronous nature of JavaScript, that didn't happen.  So I tried to use

async.series:

```
function fillBLD() {


  async.series([
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 1");
      insertRowInBLD('R01', 'Disclosure of data due to deliberate action by internal actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')
      callback(null, 'Row 1 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 2");
      insertRowInBLD('R02', 'Corruption of data due to deliberate action by internal actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')
      callback(null, 'Row 2 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 3");
      insertRowInBLD('R03', 'Unavailability of data due to deliberate action by internal actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', '', '', '', '', '')
      callback(null, 'Row 3 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 4");
      insertRowInBLD('R04', 'Disclosure of data due to attack of the communications link by internal/external actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')
      callback(null, 'Row 4 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 5");
      insertRowInBLD('R05', 'Corruption of data due to attack of the communications link by internal/external actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')
      callback(null, 'Row 5 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 6");
      insertRowInBLD('R06', 'Unavailability of data due to attack of the communications link by internal/external actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')
      callback(null, 'Row 6 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 7");
      insertRowInBLD('R07', 'Disclosure of data due to social engineering by internal/external actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')
      callback(null, 'Row 7 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 8");
      insertRowInBLD('R08', 'Corruption of data due to social engineering by internal/external actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')
      callback(null, 'Row 8 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 9");
      insertRowInBLD('R09', 'Unavailability of data due to social engineering by internal/external actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')
      callback(null, 'Row 9 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 10");
      insertRowInBLD('R10', 'Disclosure of data due to  erroneous useby internal actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')
      callback(null, 'Row 10 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 11");
      insertRowInBLD('R11', 'Corruption of data due to erroneous useby internal actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')
      callback(null, 'Row 11 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 12");
      insertRowInBLD('R12', 'Unavailability of data due to erroneous useby internal actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')
      callback(null, 'Row 12 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 13");
      insertRowInBLD('R13', 'Disclosure of data due to  unauthorized access by internal/external actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')
      callback(null, 'Row 13 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 14");
      insertRowInBLD('R14', 'Corruption of data due to unauthorized access by internal/external actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')
      callback(null, 'Row 14 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 15");
      insertRowInBLD('R15', 'Unavailability of data due to unauthorized access by internal/external actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')
      callback(null, 'Row 15 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 16");
      insertRowInBLD('R16', 'Disclosure of data due to  attack by malicious code by internal/external actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')
      callback(null, 'Row 16 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 17");
      insertRowInBLD('R17', 'Corruption of data due to attack by malicious code by internal/external actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')
      callback(null, 'Row 17 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 18");
      insertRowInBLD('R18', 'Unavailability of data due to erroneous useby internal actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')
      callback(null, 'Row 18 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 19");
      insertRowInBLD('R19', 'Disclosure of data due to improper change/maintenance by internal actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')
      callback(null, 'Row 19 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 20");
      insertRowInBLD('R20', 'Corruption of data due to improper change/maintenance by internal actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')
      callback(null, 'Row 20 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 21");
      insertRowInBLD('R21', 'Unavailability of data due to improper change/maintenance by internal actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')
      callback(null, 'Row 21 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 22");
      insertRowInBLD('R22', 'Disclosure of data due to loss or theft of device by internal actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')
      callback(null, 'Row 22 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 23");
      insertRowInBLD('R23', 'Unavailability of data due to loss or theft of device by internal actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')
      callback(null, 'Row 23 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 24");
      callback(null, 'Row 24 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 25");
      insertRowInBLD('R25', 'Corruption of data due to bypassing physical security by internal/external actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')

      callback(null, 'Row 25 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 26");
      insertRowInBLD('R26', 'Unavailability of data due to bypassing physical security by internal/external actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')
      callback(null, 'Row 26 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 27");
      insertRowInBLD('R27', 'Disclosure of data due to third-party security breach by external actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')
      callback(null, 'Row 27 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 28");
      insertRowInBLD('R28', 'Corruption of data due to  third-party security breach by external actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')
      callback(null, 'Row 28 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 29");
      insertRowInBLD('R29', 'Unavailability of data due to third-party security breach by external actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')
      callback(null, 'Row 29 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 30");
      insertRowInBLD('R30', 'Disclosure of data due to unmanaged legal, regulatory and contractual requirements by internal actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')
      callback(null, 'Row 30 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 31");
      insertRowInBLD('R31', 'Corruption of data due to unmanaged legal, regulatory and contractual requirements by internal actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')
      callback(null, 'Row 31 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 32");
      insertRowInBLD('R32', 'Unavailability of data due to unmanaged legal, regulatory and contractual requirements by internal actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')

      callback(null, 'Row 32 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 33");
      callback(null, 'Row 33 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 33");
      insertRowInBLD('R33', 'Unavailability of data due to component failure by internal/external factor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')

      callback(null, 'Row 33 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 34");
      insertRowInBLD('R34', 'Unavailability of data due to exhaustion of resources by internal/external actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')
      callback(null, 'Row 34 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 35");
      insertRowInBLD('R35', 'Unavailability of data due to environmental & natural disasters by external factor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')

      callback(null, 'Row 35 Inserted');
    },
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 36");
      insertRowInBLD('R36', 'Lack of accountability due to tampering with audit trails by internal/external actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')
      callback(null, 'Row 36 Inserted');
    },
  ], function (error, results) {
    console.log(results);
  });
}
```

However, while the console logs get executed synchronously and the results get passed in order to the callback functions:

> Task 1 Task 2 Task 3 Task 4 Task 5 Task 6 Task 7 Task 8 Task 9 Task 10
>   Task 11 Task 12 Task 13 Task 14 Task 15 Task 16 Task 17 Task 18 Task
>   19 Task 20 Task 21 Task 22 Task 23 Task 24 Task 25 Task 26 Task 27
>   Task 28 Task 29 Task 30 Task 31 Task 32 Task 33 Task 33 Task 34 Task
>   35 Task 36 [ 'Row 1 Inserted',   'Row 2 Inserted',   'Row 3 Inserted',
>   'Row 4 Inserted',   'Row 5 Inserted',   'Row 6 Inserted',   'Row 7
>   Inserted',   'Row 8 Inserted',   'Row 9 Inserted',   'Row 10
>   Inserted',   'Row 11 Inserted',   'Row 12 Inserted',   'Row 13
>   Inserted',   'Row 14 Inserted',   'Row 15 Inserted',   'Row 16
>   Inserted',   'Row 17 Inserted',   'Row 18 Inserted',   'Row 19
>   Inserted',   'Row 20 Inserted',   'Row 21 Inserted',   'Row 22
>   Inserted',   'Row 23 Inserted',   'Row 24 Inserted',   'Row 25
>   Inserted',   'Row 26 Inserted',   'Row 27 Inserted',   'Row 28
>   Inserted',   'Row 29 Inserted',   'Row 30 Inserted',   'Row 31
>   Inserted',   'Row 32 Inserted',   'Row 33 Inserted',   'Row 33
>   Inserted',   'Row 34 Inserted',   'Row 35 Inserted',   'Row 36
>   Inserted' ]

The insertRowInBLD functions are still not executed in the order that I have defined:

> row R01 has been inserted succesfully 
>   row R02 has been inserted
>   succesfully row R03 has been inserted succesfully row R04 has been
>   inserted succesfully row R05 has been inserted succesfully row R07 has
>   been inserted succesfully row R08 has been inserted succesfully row
>   R09 has been inserted succesfully row R06 has been inserted
>   succesfully row R12 has been inserted succesfully row R19 has been
>   inserted succesfully row R14 has been inserted succesfully row R17 has
>   been inserted succesfully row R22 has been inserted succesfully row
>   R28 has been inserted succesfully row R33 has been inserted
>   succesfully row R25 has been inserted succesfully row R30 has been
>   inserted succesfully row R35 has been inserted succesfully row R10 has
>   been inserted succesfully row R15 has been inserted succesfully row
>   R20 has been inserted succesfully row R26 has been inserted
>   succesfully row R31 has been inserted succesfully row R36 has been
>   inserted succesfully row R11 has been inserted succesfully row R16 has
>   been inserted succesfully row R21 has been inserted succesfully row
>   R27 has been inserted succesfully row R32 has been inserted
>   succesfully row R13 has been inserted succesfully row R18 has been
>   inserted succesfully row R23 has been inserted succesfully row R29 has
>   been inserted succesfully row R34 has been inserted succesfully

I really do not see why they still get executed asynchronously.
Any idea what may be causing this and how can I fix it?
Thank you!

Comment: Javascript is sync by nature. Promises are async. Async is a feature of the mongodb connector.

Comment: You are calling `callback` before `insertRowInBLD` completes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're currently calling the callbacks immediately, rather than waiting for the inserts to complete. This means you will immediately start all of the saves, and have no control over when they finish. Instead, you want to wait for one to finish before moving on to the next one, and for that you'll need to use the promise created by businessLaneDashboard.save(). In particular, you need to return it from insertRowInBLD:

```
function insertRowInBLD(/* args */) {
    const businessLineDashboard = new BusinessLineDashboard(
      //etc
    );
    return businessLineDashboard.save();
}
```

With the promise, you can use it's .then method to wait before calling the callback.

```
    function (callback) {
      console.log("Task 1");
      insertRowInBLD('R01', 'Disclosure of data due to deliberate action by internal actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')
        .then(() => callback(null, 'Row 1 Inserted'));
    },
```

Though now that we're using promises, i'd drop the async.series stuff and just use a chain of promises, as in:

```
insertRowInBLD('R01', 'Disclosure of data due to deliberate action by internal actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')
  .then(() => {
    return insertRowInBLD('R02', 'Corruption of data due to deliberate action by internal actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '')
  })
  .then(() => {
    return insertRowInBLD('R03', 'Unavailability of data due to deliberate action by internal actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', '', '', '', '', '')
  })
  // etc
```

If async/await is an option for you, then working with the promises can be made even simpler:

```
async function fillBLD() {
  await insertRowInBLD('R01', 'Disclosure of data due to deliberate action by internal actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '');
  await insertRowInBLD('R02', 'Corruption of data due to deliberate action by internal actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', 'Low', '', '', '', '');
  await insertRowInBLD('R03', 'Unavailability of data due to deliberate action by internal actor', 'E. Not significant', 'Partially effective', '', '', '', '', '');
  // etc
}
```